# Suppose that $C$ is an invertible matrix (such that $CAC^{-1}$ is defined). Find an eigenvalue for the matrix $B$ where $B = CAC^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

trying to do  some homework but I can't make any sense of this problem.

Suppose that $C$ is an invertible matrix (such that $CAC^{-1}$ is defined). Find an eigenvalue for the matrix $B$
where $B = CAC^{-1}$.

Since its invertible there is no $0$ eigenvalue, $CAC^{-1}$ is defined I don't understand how $B$ could be $CAC^{-1}$.

Suppose that a square matrix  has a characteristic polynomial $(\lambda-2)^3(\lambda-4)(\lambda-5)$

Comment: Are you given that $A$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: I am not given a diagonal matrix no, just a polynomial - updated with polynomial given.

Comment: @BrandonZywoo Is the polynomial the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Comment: Yes it is! sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to show that $A$ and $B$ share eigenvalues.

Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$. Then, $$(CAC^{-1})(Cv)=(CAC^{-1}C)v=(CA)v=C(Av)$$ $$=C(\lambda v)=\lambda Cv$$ Thus, $Cv$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Thus, $B$ shares eigenvalues with the matrix $A$.

Now you are given the characteristic polynomial of $A$. The zeros of that polynomial are the eigenvalues of $A$. Since we have showed that all the eigenvalues of $A$ are the eigenvalues of $B$, what can you say about the eigenvalues of $B$?